# Re.findall display row of tekst

Tags: python

I got the following code:

```
import re

text = "He was carefully disguised but captured quickly by police."
print re.findall(r"\w+ly", text)
```

The output now is:

```
['carefully', 'quickly']
```

How can I make my re.findall so, that it will displays the whole row where it found something. Like when there is a lot of tekst and I am searching for everything with my name in it. How can I let it display the whole row of tekst and not just only my name.

Comment: Well, you're printing the search results. If you want to print the whole row (the `text` variable in your example), tell it to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `re.findall()` returned anything, then print the row:

```
text = "He was carefully disguised but captured quickly by police."
lines = [text, 't', 'l']
for line in lines:
    if re.findall(r"\w+ly", line):
        print line
```